# Using generated classes from XSD with generated classes from WSDL - how to work together?

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, wsdl

I have been given a WSDL file, which I have added Service Reference to in VS2013. It generated some classes fine.

I was later given a load of XSD's which are all related. I used xsd.exe to create a single .CS file.

I don't really understand how they are interchangable.

For example, one of the WSDL classes is like this:

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://namespacepath/")]
    public partial class ExampleWSDLClass: object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private System.Xml.XmlNode[] anyField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Any {
            get {
                return this.anyField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Any");
            }
        }
```

and then the corresponding object in the XSD class is defined like this

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class ExampleXsdClass{

    private string customerNumberField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string CustomerNumber {
        get {
            return this.customerNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.customerNumberField = value;
        }
    }
```

There is probably a very simple answer which will be a lightbulb moment, but how do I get these two to work together?

Comment: If you have a valid wsdl you don't need any other schema. Did you ask why you are given those XSDs? I don't think anyone here can answer that.

Comment: @Filburt that's not correct for all situations. The wsdl describes a service and its contracts, it cannot contain any simple or complex types used by the service. When you talking about a wsdl url, you can create a complete proxy for a service, but a wsdl file contains only data about the service (location and operations).

Comment: @RicardoPontual I was referring to the wsdl file created by accessing a webservices' wsdl url which will contain everything you need to interact with the webservice. In any case the question is almost impossible to answer this here and should be answered by the provider of said resources.

Comment: @Filburt I understood, and about the question you're right, any doubt about the xsd and wsdl should be better answered by the provider.